# Exposed Node Title Filter is being applied when it shouldn't be

Tags: views, 6

So this is a bit of a long shot but I wanted to see if anyone else has encountered this issue.

I've implemented a view that uses a custom base table that contains a relation to the node table. Some records on my custom table do not have an associated node id.

There is an exposed filter set for the Node Title so that the records can be filtered down to ones related to a specific node.

The problem I'm encountering is that records with no associated node id do not appear on the view. It's caused by the node title view filter inserting it's where clause despite not having any value to filter by.

Is there anyway around this problem?

For instance, can I implement a custom filter for the node title? The filter part is easy, but overriding the existing node field configuration seems more complicated.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!